# Redirection to another url is not working after the deployment

Tags: node.js, express

```html
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var open = require('open')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
    open('https://google.com');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT})
});
```

using the above code. I'm unable to redirect to the google.com after deployment and its working in localhost

test URL: https://redirecttestok.herokuapp.com/

Please help me to resolve this issue or help me with alternative package.

Comment: That's **not** how you redirect a request in Express.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how to redirect in Express - use this instead;

```
res.redirect(301, 'https://google.com');
```

Edit: You can't do the `res.send` first. You can only respond to a request once. The result in its entirety:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var open = require('open');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(301, 'https://google.com');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: no its not working. error Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: const time = () => {
 for(time in times) {
  if(Date.now() > times[time].time) {
   open(times[time]..url);
  }
 }
}  doing something like this res.redirect will also not work that's why i used open. help pls

Comment: got it but what's in this case const time = () => { for(time in times) { if(Date.now() > times[time].time) { open(times[time]..url); } } } in this case i want to open a new tab for this particular url

Comment: I don't think you can send multiple pages as a response on a single request. Handle it on the frontend and send formatted data - such as json.

Comment: but if i'm using open(url) its working intentionally..not working after deplyment.

Comment: Doesn't "open" just open the tabs locally on your machine, meaning it wont work in your live environment?

To send multiple responses use res.write and res.end, but i don't think you can trigger multi-tab behaviour.

Comment: he also posted this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509603/how-to-redirect-in-express-js which shows a miscomprehension of browser side and server side concepts. his real aim is to open multiple tabs in the browser at some timeouts. this need to be done browser side. no "open" package. "redirect" is not the right word. window.open is the solution. and it cant be called on express's side. its on browser side.