# How to redirect in express js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

> Please help me with some solutions.

in simple, I made this API (https://lampmeet.herokuapp.com/api/v1)
username: test
token: test
and If the Date. now is greater than the meeting time then open the meet URL in the new tab. and it should need to check every second.

Comment: what do you call production ? a server, with graphical interface ?

Comment: Production means like when I'm uploading it on heroku to make it public

Comment: so you are trying to "open" a graphical tool, on a remote headless server :) its normal it doesnt work.

Comment: So then how I can do this. pls check the update question

Comment: to open a new tab in the browser run this : window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank');

Comment: no bro window.open will not work!

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the applicable code.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in https://www.npmjs.com/package/open

This is meant to be used in command-line tools and scripts, not in the browser.

if you try to run it on a remote server it won't open a link in your current browser, it will try to open it on the server itself.